# Why Android TimingLogger is not able to print logs?

Tags: android, execution-time, benchmarking, android-log

I am trying to use TimingLogger for checking time consumed for a particular method and its statements. But Android TimingLogger is not able to print logs.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> If the Log.isLoggable is not enabled to at least the Log.VERBOSE level
> for that tag at creation time then the addSplit and dumpToLog call
> will do nothing.

If you simply looking for logs as explained in [https://developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html), you will not be able to see logs. So use below command in adb:

`adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag VERBOSE`

**Note**: **MyTag** is the first parameter you passed when creating new TimingLogger as below:

`TimingLogger timings = new TimingLogger("MyTag", "MyMethodName");`

And there you are. Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from changing the log level, I also had to reset the TimeLogger to set it's `mDisabled` flag. You can do so by `timingLogger.reset()`

Comment: Sometimes using only timingLogger.reset() logs do not show so in that case we have to run the command  adb shell setprop log.tag.MyTag VERBOSE

Answer (score 0):

After the code is updated with `timings.addSplit("MyTag:onviewcreated");` in all places , **at last of the function you are working on, try calling** `timings.dumpToLog();`

TimeLogger does not seem to work well inside async / background threads.